# How prove this integral inequality $\int_{0}^{1}(f(x)+g(x))dx\ge\int_{0}^{1}f(g(x))dx$?

Tags: inequality

> let two function $f(x),g(x):[0,1]\to [0,1]$ are **Continuous function**,and $f(x)$ **strictly monotone increasing**,
>
> show that
> $$\int_{0}^{1}(f(x)+g(x))dx\ge\int_{0}^{1}f(g(x))dx$$

I am not comfortable with compositions and don't have any idea on how to deal with the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

This problem is from analysis problem book excises by Min hui xie (This book exsice problem it is very hard)[see this](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=N0NRSgokMJrbE-P5PvFIJwYiAWfaLCDZZG0VuEE79C1JgrHO4bVjNYXKIUPu5WtuAoRjC8QKU4PUnWakgCpOxq)

[image]

Comment: maybe can use Geometric meaning to explain?

Comment: Put your claim forth!

Comment: May we know the context behind this question ? It looks like  homework/contest, and answering a homework/contest question which does not show the OP's work wouldn't feel right. "I don't have any idea" is surely not the way to go.

Comment: It would be great if your graph could be a bit more... readable..

Comment: Is $f(x)$ strictly monotone increasing?

Comment: @NicholasStull,Yes,Thank you,I have edit it

Comment: @NicholasStull "increasing" usually means strictly increasing (otherwise, it would have been non-decreasing).

Comment: @chinamath For $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x) = x^{1/n}$ the right hand side is $1/2$, not $1$.

Comment: @Winther,Oh,I know ,But also such inequality

Comment: @ClementC. I was just confirming that.  Some books differ in convention, which is why I asked.